# How can QoSFilter be used in sparkjava?

Tags: spark-java

I am new to spark java. How can the embedded jetty server be configured to use

[QosFilter](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/QoSFilter.html)? I went through the documentation but couldn't find anything relevant to connect.